# Bash: Alternative to cat in reading/writing to named pipe

Tags: bash

I am starting a process, and redirecting its output to a named pipe. I'm reattaching to the named pipe with with `cat > $pipe`. How do I set the named pipe to die when the process' stdout dies without polling for the parent process' death?

Aside from that, what else besides `cat` can be used to open named pipes?

Comment: This is confusing. Is your Java process going to read the pipe, or write it, or both? You're using it for what purpose exactly, to redirect some logging output to a terminal?

Comment: If your process (originally a Java process) is writing to the FIFO, you probably want your `cat` process to read from the FIFO, not write to it as well as the other process.  Any process that can open a file can open a FIFO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a fifo is always *ready* to read and write, so a program like `cat` and `tail -f` will not stop reading, ever. What you want to check is whether there's a process that writes to that file, and if there is no such process, stop reading. (btw, the best way to read a file, is to `read` it.)

`lsof` can tell you who reads and writes from/to a specified file. Look in its man page, and try something like:

```
while lsof /path/to/fifo
do 
    read -r line < /path/to/fifo
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```

I am not sure, and do not have the time to look into lsof, to find out which option outputs only processes that *write* to that file. Please look into that on the man page.
So, as long as there is a process that writes to the fifo, this scripts read a line and prints it. Once there is no process writting to the file, the loop breaks and the script exits.

I do not know of another way to check whether there is a process writing to a file other than using `lsof`. If anyone does know a more standard way, I would like to know too.

Comment: By default, the `open()` on a FIFO will hang until there's another process which also opens it for 'the other' mode.  That is, if process A opens the FIFO for writing, the `open()` will hang until process B opens the FIFO for reading, or vice versa.  Once a FIFO is opened, a `read()` on the FIFO will hang until there is some data to read; a `write()` may hang if there is no space left in the FIFO buffer for the data to be written (so considerably more data has been written than read).  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ However, `cat` won't detect EOF when reading from a FIFO until it has (a) read all the data and (b) no process has it open for writing.  Similarly, a `write()` won't fail until there is no process that has the FIFO open for reading.  Non-blocking I/O and opening a FIFO for reading and writing subverts the normal behaviour; be cautious.

Answer (score 0):

`cat > $pipe` writes to the pipe, not read from it.

If you want to read data from the pipe and print it on the terminal try `tail -f $pipe`.

The `-f` option keeps `tail` running and have it print output when new data is written to the pipe.

See also this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) from Linux Journal.

Comment: With `cat > $pipe` you redirect the output of cat to the pipe, in other words you're writing to the pipe.

Comment: `tail -f -n +1 $file` for reading from file begin, `tail -f -n +1` for reading from std output pipe begin, `tail -f $pipe` for reading from pipe (fs pipe begin is misty thing). see https://askubuntu.com/questions/509881/tail-reading-an-entire-file-and-then-following/509915#509915